# sbs 2008 to office 365 staged migration

Tags: microsoft-office-365, windows-sbs-2008, exchange-migration

I'm looking for some help with a client. He currently has sbs 2008 with his email server on site and due to it being dropped from official support I've suggested that he moves to office 365.

What he wants to do is have him and another user run a pilot where they use and get used to office 365 while everyone else at the site continues to use office 2007 and sbs. The plan is for them to field any of the easy questions/basic training that the other users will have once the whole office is migrated to 365.

I've done some searching and its looking like I want to do is a staged migration but it seems that it is not supported. Every search that I have done has come up with a cut-over or just a full migration. Not really sure where to go from here as this is my first migration and I know there are some sneaky features missing from sbs which can make this a bit problematic. Any help would be appreciated and if I've missed some key details, let me know and I'll provide that info.

Also since this is my first post here, let me know if there are any formatting or general mistakes in this post so I can make sure I don't make the same mistakes in future questions that I'll inevitably have.

Comment: Why can't you [do a staged migration](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Perform-a-staged-migration-of-email-to-Office-365-83bc0b69-de47-4cc4-a57d-47e478e4894e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)?

Comment: I was looking for something that specifically mentions sbs 2008. But if there isn't any real difference between the two then I guess that link answers my question. Appreciate the response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Exchange 2007 in SBS 2008, we can do **Cutover migration** (less than 2000 mailboxes), **Stage migration** (more than 2000 mailboxes) or **PST file by Office 365 Import Service** to migrate mailbox to Office 365.

Refer to:
[Ways to migrate multiple email accounts to Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ways-to-migrate-multiple-email-accounts-to-office-365-0a4913fe-60fb-498f-9155-a86516418842),
[Decide on a migration path](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Decide-on-a-migration-path-0d4f2396-9cef-43b8-9bd6-306d01df1e27)

Moreover, Office 2003 is too old and not supported anymore, upgrade it to Outlook 2013 or later.

Comment: Ah sorry meant office 2007 not 2003. I'll edit the OP. 
Thanks for those links, I'll take a look.